Dynamically averaging data Per ID Per Time period
I have the following Table below (more detailed in the Image):
Sample Data




Name
Date
ID
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3




Brian Aga
3/7/2024
332235
NA
NA
No


Brian Aga
3/8/2024
450086
NA
NA
No


Brian Aga
3/14/2024
268563
No
Yes
NA


Gwen Jolly
3/15/2024
227115
Yes
Yes
Yes


Gwen Jolly
3/19/2024
866189
NA
NA
NA


Gwen Jolly
3/20/2024
655908
NA
NA
NA


Helen Abella
3/14/2024
436578
No
Yes
NA


Helen Abella
3/8/2024
209037
NA
NA
NA


Brian Aga
3/14/2024
313267
No
Yes
NA


Brian Aga
4/19/2024
268552
No
Yes
NA


Brian Aga
4/29/2024
763410
No
Yes
NA


Gwen Jolly
4/17/2024
566422
NA
NA
Yes


Gwen Jolly
4/17/2024
776709
NA
NA
NA


Gwen Jolly
4/16/2024
750650
NA
Yes
NA


Helen Abella
3/29/2024
764914
NA
NA
No



I am looking to be able to select a User and then have the subsequent Metrics for Average Last Month, Average the Month Before, and YTD Average populate. YTD Average cannot be the averages per month averaged out, it is the total data Average to date.
What I am actually measuring is the answers from Questions 1, 2, and 3 and the number of Yes answers against the total of Yes and No answers per month per User. It is being calculated with a =CountIF()/SUM(CountIFS()) statement.

Note: Sometimes months of data are skipped, so it would have to populate based on the last recorded months data and not the last calendar month. In the sample image the Orange highlighted area is where and how it would need to populate.

For a small data set like this for every group of names per month sections I was using: =COUNTIF(D2:F4,"Yes")/SUM(COUNTIFS(D2:F4,{"No","Yes"}))
...per row highlighted in Green in the Sample Data, but this requires me to write different formulas in different cells and refer back to different cells differently, it is not efficient along with monthly maintenance vs a drag and drop new data solution...furthermore if the data isn't grouped properly it causes more problems and inaccuracies

How do you get 50% for Brian Aga in Average the Month Before:?

See even now i'm running into problems if the data is not arranged together, With this question i'm trying to bypass that altogether,

Sorry my mistake it shouldn't be 50% , my question is How do you get 25% for Brian Aga in Average the Month Before:?

By using =COUNTIF(D2:F4,"Yes")/SUM(COUNTIFS(D2:F4,{"No","Yes"})), but this method misses data not grouped in the same month such as Row 10 which is also for Brian Aga and March, but not included in the calculation

Try this: =LET(α, (TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),{-1,-2}),"e-m")=TEXT(B2:B16,"e-m"))*(I2=A2:A16), δ, D2:F16, φ, FILTER(δ, TAKE(α,,1),""), ε, FILTER(δ, TAKE(α,,-1),""), VSTACK(IFERROR(SUM(N(φ="Yes"))/SUM(N(φ<>"NA")),0),IFERROR(SUM(N(ε="Yes"))/SUM(N(ε<>"NA")),0)))

Is this for "Average Last Month," Average the Month Before," or "YTD Average?" as the highlighted Orange section answered is what i'm seeking

For both : "Average Last Month," Average the Month Before," for YTD Average you need to use the YEAR() function to get the data. Try first and see what you get let me know.

Not sure how and where to plug the "Year" function in

Have you tried the other ones? Is your output matching ?

Yes i have tried it for the other ones, it seems to work. However, for my actual data i'm not sure how to plug this in because the Dashboard is on a separate sheet from the data... i'm not familiar with any of these symbols either... wow this is quite advanced.

I2 is the name dropdown! If anyone answers fine, I will take time to post. My computer is running some issues. so couldn't post it

Thank you, i look forward to it... yes i figured out the I2 part, just got lost in all these symbols.

posted in answers

I've added an ALTERNATIVE EXAMPLE i'm seeking to the original question, based on the original answers it is not structured for the new view. Not sure what route to take from the foundation of the last answer.

That should be a new question, one question per post per site rules and guidelines.

But nevermind, i will update, give me sometime.

My mistake, i thought it was almost the same question, just to display it differently so didn't consider submitting a whole new question.  Look forward to your solution

Just following up if it might be better I submit a separate question for this alternate version?

Ok which example i should consider is it the alternative one?

Yes, please that is correct

Here is the following formula, which one could use to resolve:


=LET(
     _CriteriaOne, (TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),{-1,-2}),"e-m")=TEXT(B2:B16,"e-m")),
     _CriteriaTwo, (I2=A2:A16),
     _Questions, D2:F16,
     _LastMonth, FILTER(_Questions, TAKE(_CriteriaOne,,1)*_CriteriaTwo,""),
     _MonthBefore, FILTER(_Questions, TAKE(_CriteriaOne,,-1)*_CriteriaTwo,""),
     _YTD, FILTER(_Questions, _CriteriaTwo,""),
     VSTACK(IFERROR(SUM(N(_LastMonth="Yes"))/SUM(N(_LastMonth<>"NA")),0),
     IFERROR(SUM(N(_MonthBefore="Yes"))/SUM(N(_MonthBefore<>"NA")),0),
     IFERROR(SUM(N(_YTD="Yes"))/SUM(N(_YTD<>"NA")),0)))



for this should I also replace the "0" with "N/a" so that a 0 is only calculated when it is measured against a Yes/No?

Are you using two different user accounts? This

Was unaware i had an account a long time ago and made a new, now found i can only ask questions on certain accounts vs other accounts... so its become a balancing act. This question was asked through the new account, but my other account doesn't have enough rep to ask the follow-up question so i have to use this account to ask it

@shade206 ok, I got confused, I posted my comment in your new question, but you asked me here. So i was like did i do something wrong

No problem, my concern is that i am getting a bunch of 0's which should be N/A and not considered in a YTD calculation, but are. and thus my YTD is actually incorrect.

@shade206 yes change this part into: IFERROR(SUM(N(_YTD="Yes"))/SUM(N(_YTD<>"")),"NA"))) let me know if that helps. Or just use. IFERROR(SUM(N(_YTD="Yes"))/COUNTA(_YTD),"NA"))) the reason why i excluded the NA in the counts because of your post where it says to exclude it so i did
